# essl finger print u990 - How to retrieve the data through any language?

Tags: fingerprint, biometrics, time-tracking, time-and-attendance

I need to fetch the records from eSSL finger print biometrics device. 
Does eSSL finger print use any database to store the data? How can I connect the Datasource and fetch the records through Java or any scripting language?

Answer (score 0):

While installing Select the favorable database for the java or other Scripting languages. 
For java can use Oracle as database.
use the Connection script to connect to database in Other Scripting languages.
Study the structure of the database and retrieve the code from the database.

Answer (score -2):

Yes. ESSL uses three databases, for example: MS-SQL, MS-access and Oracle. When you install the software it will create a database if your system already has one of the above installed.